# Get user username/email after webapp SSO authentification (Azure WebApp)

Tags: python, docker, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Webapp running a Docker container (with Python & streamlit). I have secured the access to this webapp by adding a Microsoft SSO allowing only users from my organization to access the application.

On top of this, I would like to get the username or email of the user after the authentication so I can give the users differents levels of access inside the webapp. I have searched through the vast Microsoft documentation but I was not able to find my way through it. Is someone able to put me on the right path to tackle this problem?

For now, I have namely tried to follow the following documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/app-aad-token hoping that I could access the user email with the authentication token from the Azure directory.

But I am stuck with an error that I was not able to solve:
Error 401: "An error of type 'invalid_resource' occurred during the login process: 'YYYYYYYY: The resource principal named xxxxxxxxxxxx was not found in the tenant named tenant_name. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant."

I am now doubting that what I am trying to achieve is even possible. Any help would be appreciated.

Best, clank

Comment: Could you please confirm this? As stated in the error message, this can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant, so are you the administrator? And verify if the error message’s tenant ID is the same as your tenant ID. Also ensure that your application ID/client ID are matching on both sides and all of the values set in your app settings/web.config match what you have in the portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   It is aptly written in the documentation link that you have stated that your application should have admin access and its consent for accessing the APIs in Azure databricks. Thus, as per the error statement that you are encountering, it might be that your application might not have the correct permissions to access the respective resources based on its assigned service principal.
[image: Grant admin consent]

•   Also, please take note of the token issued by the Azure AD when queried a test application created wherein when decoded on ‘jwt.io’ clearly states the information regarding the user including its email address. This access token issued using authorization code flow as stated in the documentation link connects to the application created successfully but the application fails to decode the token and use the information of the user in it for allowing the user to access its resources. The application fails to decode the token because required MSAL library redirection and resource files were missing at the location of App redirect URI. Similarly, you are trying to access email address from the issued access token and use it for giving varying levels of access in the application which is not possible as the token even if intercepted in between would not be able to access user information from it since it is encrypted using the SSL key certificate and the base 64 encoding.

[image: Access token in graph]

[image: Email ID in token]

•   To provide access to your users in varying degrees, please refer the below documentation link which describes how you can leverage dynamic groups and Azure AD conditional access policies for your requirement.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-access-management